# Geting string between two strings is finding wrong calls

Tags: php

I have prepared function which is getting the string between two strings:

```
    function getStringBetween($content,$start,$end){
        $r=explode($start,$content);
        if (isset($r[1])){
            $r=explode($end,$r[1]);
            return $r[0];
        }
        return '';

    }
```

the exaple string I have is (it is possible that this string is built from more then 100 different lines

```
$str = 'PROTOCOL-tcp80 Time ("Fri Oct 15 15:25:04 2010");
PROTOCOL-tcp Time ("Fri Oct 19 11:32:13 2010")';
```

After calling for the function like: `getStringBetween($str,"PROTOCOL-tcp",";")`

I expect to get as result string `Time ("Fri Oct 19 11:32:13 2010"` however my function is finding the first match so `PROTOCOL-tcp80` so the result is `80 Time ("Fri Oct 15 15:25:04 2010")`.

Is it possible to fix my function so it will 'catch' only exact matches without using regex expressions ?

Comment: _Fri Oct 19 11:32:13 2010_ should match as well right ?

Comment: If you are passing PROTOCOL-tcp, so after that this string goes "80 TIME...", what is wrong than?

Comment: @Justinas I was looking for TIME for `PROTOCOL-tcp` not `PROTOCOL-tcp80` i would like that to be the only match..

Comment: I think a regexp is the best solution for this. Why don't you want to do that?

Comment: @Barmar I am not quite familiar with regex'es and I thought I could avoid using those..

Comment: Regexes are a basic tool that every programmer should become familiar with. get yourself over to www.regular-expressions.info and read the tutorial

Answer (score 1):

Here's how to do it using a regular expression. `\b` matches word boundaries, so this ensures the kind of exact match you're looking for.

```
function getStringBetween($content,$start,$end){
    $start = preg_quote($start);
    $end = preg_quote($end);
    if (preg_match("/\b$start\b(.*?)\b$end\b/", $content, $match)) {
        return $match[1];
    } else {
        return '';
    }
}
```